# On Windows 7, how can I retrieve/set system (not administrator) password?

Tags: windows-7, windows, passwords

Ok, so I know on many unix variants, you can set up a root / admin user, a standard user, etc. And by default sometimes on some distros of Linux the 'root' superuser is known to have a default password. For example (example only) on an Oracle Linux distro the default password could be just 'oracle'.

Now on the Windows side, I'm trying to get into the system account as apparently access is being denied even running things as 'Administrator' on the computer, like regedit, can still deny me access.

I notice in task scheduler and a few other areas, there seems to be some special or encrypted password for the 'LocalService' & 'NetworkService' users, that by Microsoft were programmed to do things like start the task scheduler, run background processes, etc. So if there's a way to    find out the default passwords used for these accounts, that would offer a lot of help. If not able to just de-encrpyt them, then I'll reset them if anything.

Either way, is there a default system password for Windows? I essentially need super-user access to my local machine so if there's any way you can, I'd appreciate it.

P.S. I know in the past there were some exploits I used to take advantage of (for my own use) in Windows on my machine to run things at a higher privilege level. On Windows XP, killing explorer through task manager, then starting it again via schedtasks due to a security hole that allowed this, etc.

So if at all, (and this is for my machine only, I'm not trying to do this on someone else's machine) I need to gain access to the (a?) superuser account on the machine. My best bet at this point would be to use LocalService, or SYSTEM, as it'd be far powerful enough to get the stuff I need to do done.

Thanks for your help!

Regards

Comment: If you hold shift and right-click the file and select run as a different user and provide admin privileges, does this not allow the programs to work properly?

Comment: For example, I need to delete a locked key, the administrator account cannot do this, but a higher-level one, like LocalService or SYSTEM, can, because it has a higher privilege level, and therfor can delete the locked key. I've tried running regedit as administrator mode, but this does not help. But please don't try and focus the question mainly on regedit, I need this for other things as well.

Comment: Notice even though an Admin may be **initially** denied, an Admin also has the seize ownership priv and can thus change any permissions at will.

Comment: That's great I guess, surfasb, that's good news, but still doesn't help me much here. I mean if there was a way I could gain superuser privileges in Win-7 (like the exploit where you could kill explorer, then start it up again running under SYSTEM), that would be kind of helpful at times, because it doesn't require modifications to the registry or passwords or any sort.

Comment: @JohnRobertson.: The same ACLs that will lock a reg key from the Admin account can also be used to deny the System account. You can even deny file permissions to the System account.

Comment: @surfasb: I know that, but that's why I'm trying to find a way to get SU privileges in Windows without having to use otherwise 'questionable' exploits or hacks / modifications to take a higher-level of control of my PC. If I could simply do anything simple like modifying a locked registry key (say, something some antivirus adds) and need to delete it, I shouldn't have to spend 2 minutes setting permissions on it and it's subkeys trying to force it to be unlocked.

Comment: @JohnRobertson: Maybe you are doing it the wrong way.  I'm curious which keys and subkeys you need access. Rarely if ever am I messing with the ACLs of the Registry itself.  There are good tools out there to do it for you.

Comment: It might be possible to trick Windows into putting the SYSTEM SID into a user's access token, e.g., by using the pTokenGroups argument to LogonUserExExW.  You'd be getting into some pretty hard-core programming, though, and there's no telling what side-effects this might have.

Answer (score 11):

The `SYSTEM` and `NETWORK SERVICE` accounts are not real account and do not exist in the SAM – in other words, they *cannot* have a password set, and you cannot login into them. They only exist as ["well-known SIDs"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier#Well-known_security_identifiers) ([security identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier)) – Windows simply gives special treatment to such SIDs as `S-1-5-18` or `S-1-5-20`, similar to how uid 0 is special in Unix, and privileged programs can use this account by creating tokens themselves (similar to calling `setuid()`+`capset()` in Unix).

An easy way of running programs with SYSTEM privileges is via [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) from Sysinternals:

```
psexec -dsi cmd
```

However, unlike Unix *root*, not even `SYSTEM` is allowed to bypass object ACLs – that's why all registry entries, system files and other things explicitly show `SYSTEM` in their ACLs. Instead, if an administrator needs for some reason to override an object's ACL, they can take ownership of that object using *SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege*<sup>1</sup> (granted by default to all Administrators). This works because an object's owner is *always* allowed to change its ACLs, even if they explicitly deny it; this is the only<sup>2</sup> exception Windows makes.

Sometimes access is being denied due to other reasons – many antivirus programs come with "self defense" kernel drivers, which patch various functions in the Windows kernel itself and make them reject modifications to specific keys or files based solely on their name; the block is *before* the original ACL checks take place, and no permission or privilege can override it. The only way to bypass such protection is to undo the kernel modifications; any kernel debugger can be used for this. Such tools as [Kernel Detective](http://www.at4re.com/download.php?view.2) can list all entries in the SSDT, which kernel driver has modified which function, and even have commands to reset the default values.

---

<sup>1</sup> If curious, you can use Process Explorer to view all SIDs and privilege bits assigned to a particular process. You'll see that not even the system processes have any sort of generic ["override security"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OverrideCommand) privilege; instead, only [specific privileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) such as *SeImpersonate*, *SeTakeOwnership* or *SeCreateToken* exist.

<sup>2</sup> For *files*, someone holding *SeBackupPrivilege* can read a file in "backup mode" – an archive containing the data, metadata, ACLs, ownership... – then optionally modify it, and restore it to the filesystem again. That is, assuming someone has reverse-engineered the structure of these backup archives. This is not available for other kinds of objects.

Comment: Is there a way to add it to SAM then, if possible?

Comment: @JohnRobertson.: You would be breaking all sorts of components. For one, you wouldn't ever be able to login to a domain.  What in the world are you trying to do??

Comment: Make it simple to override privilege restraints? For one on several keys in the registry, I seem not to be able to take ownership of them, even as an administrator account. I can, however, take ownership of objects as an administrator with the 'Take Ownership' option. But I do see your point.

Comment: @JohnRobertson: No. `SYSTEM` only exists as a "well-known SID", lacking the domain/system identifier and RID components, which are added automatically to all SAM accounts.

Comment: @JohnRobertson. Other than taking ownership, Windows does *not* have any way of overriding object permissions from user space. (That said, many antivirus programs load their own kernel drivers and patch various kernel functions to prevent outsiders from disabling the antivirus. Microsoft does not like this kind of meddling, though; Windows tries to prevent kernel patching as of Vista.)

Comment: You may not have been able to read this, but as I was trying to type in earlier: @surfasb: I know that, but that's why I'm trying to find a way to get SU privileges in Windows without having to use otherwise 'questionable' exploits or hacks / modifications to take a higher-level of control of my PC. If I could simply do anything simple like modifying a locked registry key (say, something some antivirus adds) and need to delete it, I shouldn't have to spend 2 minutes setting permissions on it and it's subkeys trying to force it to be unlocked, as a system user you should by default have access.

Comment: @JohnRobertson: `SYSTEM` is not "higher level" in any way. **It's not magic either.** It just has more privileges *by default*, since they are necessary for services to worn, but nothing stops you from assigning the same privileges to any user account via `secpol.msc`. *However,* if a program - say, an antivirus - adds its own protection layer via kernel patching, there is **nothing** you can do while the protection is active (although it's often possible to deactivate it via kernel debugging tools; I used "Kernel Detective" once).

Comment: @JohnRobertson.: To override privilege restraints, boot from a WinPE disk, or any offline disk.  The privilege restraints are controlled by the Session Manager.  Disabling it also means winlogon never run, which means you couldn't ever login in the first place as a System account. Basically, to bypass the kernel, you have to be lower than the kernel, which at that level **has no accounts**.

Comment: @JohnRobertson: I should also note that such kernel modifications are usually made in such a way that specific files/regkeys will be denied *immediately* based solely on their path, *before* the original ACL check takes place.

Comment: @JohnRobertson.: My bad, it's the Local Authority Service that controls authorization, not the Session Manager.

Comment: Note also, if the ACL is empty, all access is implicitly denied.

Comment: And mind you, how would I go about to control ACL and/or disable it? (if possible, out of curiosity; I have seen a post where someone claimed to have disable the ACL feature)

Comment: @JohnRobertson.: By patching LSASS or the kernel to always return "allowed" in the ACL checks, similar to how games are patched to always think "license key valid" and such. (I learnt a lot by reading "no-cd crack" tutorials during math classes.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering that, I was almost about to close this question.
It's funny how that's related to no-cd cracks, by the way.

If only things were that easy.

Comment: @grawity: you can use backup/restore privilege to override file ACLs without having to deal with the "archive" format used by BackupRead/BackupWrite.  See the FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS flag for CreateFile.  Using this flag, you can read/write data regardless of the ACLs, read/change ACLs without being the owner or having explicit permission, and even do things (like setting the owner of a file to another user) that would normally be against the rules!

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Interesting, I didn't know it was available.